# How can I keep a centerd image inside an expanding div steady

Tags: html, css

I have a div, that contains an image and is set to expand with a transition.
Code Below

```
// HTML

<dic class="header">
    <div class="container">
        <img src="/images/logo.png">
    </div>
</div>

//CSS

.header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    .logo {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 360px;
        height: 100px;
        transition: all .5s;
    }
}

.header .logo.expanded {
    width: 100%
}
```

When I add the class and the container expands, the centre of the div gets recalculated constantly and the image wiggles from left to right very quickly. How can I keep the image steady?

Edit: Added more code

Edit 2:

JsFiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/349zcvkw/25/ but the problem does not seem to occur in the fiddle. in my project, the logo wiggles from left to right, with the same exact code

UPDATE:

I solved it, by using a separate div in the back to create the expanding background. Thank you all for your suggestions.

Comment: Can you please include more code... i'm unable to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I'll try, but there really isn't much more to the issue.

Comment: No biggie. I think i get what you are trying to do..

Comment: I added all the code I have used

Comment: Do you have a demo online? I think that would help a lot @FritzLloyd

Comment: @MihalMinkov I'm working on a jsfiddle right now, but on there it does not work at all.

Comment: You could host the file elsewhere and just separate the elements you need help with if it doesn't work in jsfiddle @FritzLloyd

Answer (score 1):

If you have a lot of animations triggering at the same time, your cpu may be unable to handle all the animations and you may experience slight lags in animation (which is why you would see wiggling).There are two things you can do:

1. Optimize your code by either delaying or removing animations
2. Up your cpu

As you can see below, without any extra things going on, animation seems to work fine:

```js
function toggleClass() {
  $('.container').toggleClass('expanded');
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 360px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.expanded {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://appendto.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/css3-420x210.jpg">
</div>

<div class="expanded">
  <button onclick="toggleClass()">Toggle Class</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I think I have not made sufficiently clear, what I am trying to do. The container is also centered inside a bigger container and this leads to the wiggling.

Answer (score 1):

Added `flex` into your `flex` :)

```js
function toggleClass() {
    document.querySelector('.header .logo_container').classList.toggle('expanded');
    setTimeout(toggleClass, 3000);
}

setTimeout(toggleClass, 500);
```

```css
.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: red;
}

.header .logo_container {
  width: 360px;
  height: 100px;
  transition: width .5s;
  background-color: blue;
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  color: #FFF;
}

.header .logo_container.expanded {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="logo_container">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50"> Some Text
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @FritzLloyd could you reproduce this behavior anyhow for us?

Answer (score 0):

There could be two options:

1. Style the image as a block

`.container img { display: block; margin: 0 auto; }`

2. Style the image as inline-block. That should use the text-align: center you have in the container class

`.container img { display: inline-block; }`

Comment: The second solution is kind of pointless because `img` tags aren't block elements by default, they are inline.

Comment: @awesomeguy sometimes images styled as blocks work better in terms of margins, I am not sure if it applies in this case.

Comment: Neither of those are working. I think this is because I have not made clear, what it is i am trying to do. The container is also centered and the image does stay at the center, but it wiggles during the animation. I have updated the code.